# SSIS - export to excel overwrites header row in QA but not in DEV (first row has column names = checked, HDR=yes)

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I've got an SSIS package that simply grabs data from SQL (2012) and exports it to an excel template.  The template file has first-row headers, and the connection manager has "first row has column names" checked.

In my dev environment the package works fine; headers remain intact (row 1) and rows are exported (row 2 and beyond).

I deployed the same exact code and template to our QA environment and the headers are overwritten on export (exported rows start in row 1).

Here's my connection string from the Excel conn mgr: 
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\import\template.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";

I tried reinstalling the ACE 12.0 driver package (32-bit) with no success, bounced the server with no luck either (shouldn't that always work???). Also, using the 64-bit driver is not an option for us.

Here's the environment specs:

DEV:
Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit (sp1)
SQL 2012 11.0.3000 (sp1)

QA:
Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 64 bit (sp1)
SQL 2012 11.0.3000 (sp1)

Comment: You don't happen to have that as a setting in the configuration?  It's not intermittent on the same platform, right?  It's consistently working one way on one platform and a different way on the other platform, right?

Comment: Yeah I guess "intermittent" is a bit misleading - it is consistently happening one way in DEV, and another way in QA.  No configuration settings for the connection manager unfortunately.

Comment: RESOLVED: I have no explanation why this worked, but I just tried reinstalling the ACE 12.0 driver for the second time (simply ran out of other options) and it works now.  Go figure.

Comment: Specific problem, no obvious answer other than OP re-installed and it fixed it.